# How can I order search results by the post date?

Tags: templating

I want to order my search results by the post date (not the created on date).  And, this did not work...

```
{% if entries|length %}
    {% for post in entries.groupBy('postDate') %}
        {% include 'partials/card-standard-4' %}
    {% endfor %}                            
{% else %}
    <p>Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.orderBy('foo').all() %}
```

There is an `orderBy` property you can use on the query